# Zipping Together Multiple Nested Lists

Tags: java, arraylist

Before I write a bunch of code, I'm curious if there are any out-of-the-box methods or libraries that can do this?

Imagine there's 4 ArrayLists.

```
cities = [[["New York", "Albany"],["Los Angeles"]]]
populations = [[[8000, 1000],[2000]]]
states = [["New York", "California"]]
country = ["USA"]
```

I want to be able to do zip-like operations on these, for example combining these lists to produce:

```
city_populations = [
{"city": "New York", "population": "8000", "state": "New York", "Country": "USA"},
... and the other cities similarly]
```

Does such a java library or function exist or is this something I need to build?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

google tells me [google guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) will do this kind of thing